# JPA Custom repository Not an entity: class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

friends. Help me solve the problem. I use spring jpa. I make all requests from RestController by specifying the repository with the @Autowired annotation.
I know that you can create a repository class and inherit JpaRepository, but I want to figure out how to use my custom repository. Of course, if I use JpaRepository, then there are no errors.

My Configuration class:

```
package net.sunnikolay.multipledb.config;

@Configuration
    @PropertySource( { "classpath:application.properties" } )
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "net.sunnikolay.multipledb.repository.ab",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "abEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "abTransactionManager"
)
public class AbHttpApiDBConfiguration {
    
    @Value( "${db.ab.datasource.hibernate.dialect}" )
    private String dialect;
    
    @Value( "${db.ab.datasource.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}" )
    private String hbmDdl;
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "db.ab.datasource" )
    public DataSource abDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean abEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource( abDataSource() );
        em.setPackagesToScan( "net.sunnikolay.multipledb.domain.ab" );
        
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter( vendorAdapter );
        final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbmDdl );
        properties.put( "hibernate.dialect", dialect );
        em.setJpaPropertyMap( properties );
        
        return em;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager abTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( abEntityManager().getObject() );
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
}
```

My Entity:

```
package net.sunnikolay.multipledb.domain.ab;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "columns", schema = "invitro_report")
public class TColumn {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "report_name")
    private String reportName;
    
    @Column(name = "index")
    private int index;
    
    @Column(name = "field")
    private String field;
    
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String desc;
    
    public TColumn() {
    }
    
    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }
    
    public void setReportName( String reportName ) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }
    
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
    
    public void setIndex( int index ) {
        this.index = index;
    }
    
    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
    
    public void setField( String field ) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    
    public void setTitle( String title ) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    
    public void setDesc( String desc ) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    
}
```

My AbRepositoryCustom:

```
package net.sunnikolay.multipledb.repository.ab;

@Repository
public interface AbRepositoryCustom {
    
    List<TColumn> findByName( String name );
    
}
```

My AbRepositoryCustomImpl:

```
package net.sunnikolay.multipledb.repository.ab;

@Repository
public class AbRepositoryCustomImpl implements AbRepositoryCustom {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;
    
    @Override
    public List<TColumn> findByName( String name ) {
        List<TColumn> result = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder        cb   = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<TColumn> cq   = cb.createQuery( TColumn.class );
            Root<TColumn>          root = cq.from( TColumn.class );
            
            Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[ 1 ];
            predicates[ 0 ] = cb.equal( root.get( "reportName" ), name );
            
            cq.select( root ).where( predicates );
            
            TypedQuery<TColumn> query = manager.createQuery( cq );
            result = query.getResultList();
        }
        catch ( NoResultException ignore ) {}
        catch ( Exception jce ) {
            jce.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

When I make a request, on the line *Root root = cq.from( TColumn.class );* an **"Not an entity: class net.sunnikolay.multipledb.domain.ab.TColumn** error occurs.

Comment: Do you have multiple `EntityManagerFactory` instances? If so you are getting the wrong one, if not, why the manual configuration? The `@EnableJpaRepositories` is useless as you aren't using Spring Data JPA but are writing your own implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum , Yes, I use multiple `EntityManagerFactory`. I managed to complete the request, I added the annotation `@PersistenceContext(UnitName = "abEntityManager")` in `AbRepositoryCustomImpl`. Is this approach correct? or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom repositories but like this, you will have to extend JpaRepository

```
public interface AbRepositoryCustom extends JpaRepository<Store, Long> {
 List<TColumn> findByName( String name );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I need. I chose the custom repository direction because I plan to use complex queries and I am interested in the approach to creating a custom repository

Comment: You can have complex queries like this @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = 1")
Collection<User> findAllActiveUsers();  or native queries like this @Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM USERS u WHERE u.status = 1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<User> findAllActiveUsersNative();